# Question on union of subsets of a given set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

**Edit** Suppose $n,k$ to be positive integers. Find the minimum integer $\ell$ such that for any $\ell$ distinct subsets $A_1,\dots,A_{\ell}$ of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ each having cardinality $k$ we have
$$
A_1\cup\dots\cup A_{\ell}=\{1,\dots,n\}.
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds wrong.  You can find $\binom{n-1}{k}$ distinct $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ where none of them contain the element $n$ itself.  $\binom{n-1}{k}$ might be *much* more than $n+1-k$.  Now... if we were to have $\binom{n-1}{k}+1$ distinct $k$-element subsets on the other hand...

Comment: I suppose you require $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: $n=4$, $k=2$, $A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_2=\{1,3\}$, $A_3=\{2,3\}$ seems to be a counterexample

Comment: Of course, I forgot to include that $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: With the edit, that completely changed the flavor of the problem.  My initial comment still stands, showing why regardless the value of $n$ and $k$ you can have $\binom{n-1}{k}$ distinct subsets of size $k$ who do *not* union to equal $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and you should be able to reason why adding one to this implies they *will*.  It makes me wonder how the original question was phrased and where the value of $n+1-k$ ever came from in the first place... was it just your guess as to the answer of the current version of the question?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I actually only thought of the cases $k=1,n-1,n$. In those cases I believe that that value worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n-1}{k}$ distinct $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.  Taking all of these and unioning them together only results in $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.

This shows that we are capable of finding $\binom{n-1}{k}$ distinct $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that their union is not equal to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ by just taking the $\binom{n-1}{k}$ subsets alluded to in the previous line.  Thus, $\ell > \binom{n-1}{k}$

Now... suppose we were to try to form a maximal collection of size $\ell-1$ of subsets of size $k$ whose union is not equal to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  Then their union is missing an element.  Without loss of generality, suppose it were missing $n$.  Then all of these subsets would have also been subsets of size $k$ of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ of which there exist only $\binom{n-1}{k}$ of them.  This implies that $\ell-1\leq \binom{n-1}{k}$

So, since $\ell>\binom{n-1}{k}$ and $\ell -1 \leq \binom{n-1}{k}$ that implies that $\ell$ is precisely equal to $\binom{n-1}{k}+1$